# Skipping extra keyword arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, keyword-argument

I defined a method:

```
def method(one: 1, two: 2)
   [one, two]
end
```

and when I call it like this:

```
method one: 'one', three: 'three'
```

I get:

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: three
```

I do not want to extract desired keys from a hash one by one or exclude extra keys. Is there way to circumvent this behaviour except defining the method like this:

```
def method(one: 1, two: 2, **other)
  [one, two, other]
end
```

Comment: Why can't you do it like `method(one: 1, two: 2, **other)`?

Comment: These `**other` parameters seem to be an extra

Comment: Do you want to refer to the other parameters in the method body? And at the same time you don't want to refer to that in the method profile? If so, then what you are trying to do does not make sense. How can you refer to a particular parameter without receiving that in the method definition?

Comment: One of the reasons is not to bother about order of parameters, but there are also other demands of doing like so

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't want to write the `other` as in `**other`, you can omit it.

```
def method(one: 1, two: 2, **)
  [one, two]
end
```

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't work under ruby 2.0.0, which is used in my current project. Therefore I still get the same error

Comment: It does work on Ruby 2.2. I think it should work on Ruby 2.0 too. What exactly is your environment? I hope you are not going to say that you tried it only on IRB, on which it does not work regardless of the Ruby version.

Comment: This also doesn't work if you, despite all guidance and like I do, have the tendency to declare methods without parentheses.

Comment: Nice! Love it, I was looking exactly for this.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it works in ruby 2.0, but you can try using `**_` to ignore the other arguments.

```
def method(one: 1, two: 2, **_)
```

In terms of memory usage and everything else, I believe there's no difference between this and `**other`, but underscore is a standard way to mute an argument in ruby.

Comment: If I wanted to ignore all but :one and :two I would do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to approach this is with an options hash.  You will see this, frequently:

```
def method_name(opts={})
  one = opts[:one] || 1  # if caller doesn't send :one, provide a default
  two = opts[:two] || 2  # if caller doesn't send :two, provide a default

  # etc
end
```

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but I am particularly interesting about using keyword arguments, not in about hash of options

Comment: Ah, OK.  Well in that case if you want to ignore the others, I have seen `**_` as the suggested name for the double splat at the end.